# how filter custom data returned from valuePreparefunction in ng2 smart table

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I use the ng2 smart table,
my problem is the filter because i returned the custom data from valueprepareFunction of ng2 smart table,

i Have this....

```
columns: {
id: {
  title: 'Id',
  type: 'string'
},
surname: {
  title: 'surname',
  type: 'string'
},
name: {
  title: 'name',
  type: 'string'
},
date: {
  title: 'date',
  valuePrepareFunction: (value) => {
    if (!value) return '';
    return moment(value).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
  },
}
```

}

the value is a timeStamp fetch from the db,
when i try to filter from the table, her filter through timestamp but i want filter with this format 'DD/MM/YYYY.

How Can change the search input in timestamp before filter ?

Answer (score 6):

I resolved with filterFunction in ng2-smart-table settings...

```
data_pratica: {
  title: 'date',
  type: 'string',
  valuePrepareFunction: (value) => {
    // example of value.... value = 1543105073896
    // value is timeStamp
    if (!value) return '';
    return moment(value).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
  },
  filterFunction: (cell?: any, search?: string) => {
    // cell? is the value of the cell, in this case is a timeStamp
    if (search.length > 0) {
      return moment(cell).format('DD/MM/YYYY').match(search);
    }
  }
}
```